# Java opening external program

Tags: java, runtime, exec

I try to run external application from my program but nothing happens application dosen't start can you tell me what is wrong?

```
public class Wag {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime() ;
      Process p  = rt.exec( "C:/Users/Remnat/Desktop/WeightTool/WeightTool/WeightTool.exe" );
   }
}
```

Comment: Open a command console (cmd.exe) then copy paste the full path. I believe it's wrong.

Comment: Alternatively you may try to use something like `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("path"))` if you really get stuck...

Comment: Thanks tony it wordked :)